# How to tell TS explicitly that the return value of a function will be expected to be of a certain type?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

If I have something like,

```
const ChildComponent = ({value}: {value: string}) => {
    return <div>{value}</div
}

const ParentComponent = () => {
    return (
        <ChildComponent value={getValue(true)} />
    )
}

const getValue = (getCurrent?: boolean): Array<string> | string => {
    const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear()

    if (getCurrent) return currentYear.toString()

    return Array.from({length: 5}, (_, index) => (currentYear + index).toString())
}
```

I get a Typescript error,

```
<ChildComponent value={getValue(true)} />
                ^^^^^
Type 'string[] | string' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'
  Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

How do I ensure TS, that the prop `value` passed to `ChildComponent` will be of type `string`?

Comment: `ChildComponent` value prop is expecting a `string`, but `getValue` returns `Array<string> | string`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be solved by [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions)

A typical use case is angle-bracket syntax:

```js
const value: string = <string> getValue(true)
```

However, `<string>` will conflict in tsx files because it can be confused with html tags.

In this case, you can use as-style assertion for jsx and tsx files, typescript has prepared for you:

```js
<ChildComponent value={getValue(true) as string} />
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems a problem with your `ChildComponent`. It's expecting only string but possible values could be a `string` or `string array`.

You could update your child component as follow:

```
const ChildComponent = ({value}: {value: string | Array<string>}) => {
    return <div>{value}</div
}
```